# Move UIImageView from A to B

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiimageview, animatewithduration

I need to move an UIImageView from x,y to x,y1.
This is what i have. I tried lots of different codes in `-(void)animation`, most using `animateWithDuration` but none seems to work. It just doesn't do anything. I must be missing something. Is .h correct? How would you make the image move? I then have to loop that, how can i do that? It's my first time with animate, I can't figure out what to do, it has to be simple. Thanks in Advance.

---

in .h I connected it this way

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ImageBeaconViewController : UIViewController {

    __weak IBOutlet UIImageView *blueView;
}

@end
```

the in .m I've got

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self animation];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

....

 - (void)animation{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:3 animations:^{
        blueView.alpha = 1;
        blueView.center = CGPointMake(blueView.center.x , blueView.center.y +??);
    }];
}
```

??= I still have to decide how much I want it to move
This way the app crashes as soon as I get to the screen with the animation

Comment: what is exception can you send

Comment: You have the outlet connected right?

Comment: i have a number, but just a random number, i still can't get it to move so i dont bother finding the right y either yet

Comment: it says "libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException"

Comment: Now I'm trying: .h |#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

°interface ImageBeaconViewController : UIViewController {

    __weak IBOutlet UIImageView *blue;
}
°property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *blue;

°end|
.m in void animation |[UIView animateWithDuration:5 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                     animations:^{
                         CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(100,100,1024,768);
                         self.blue.frame = newFrame;
                         
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {}]; |

Comment: try restarting your xCode

Comment: Do you have any yellow warning triangles in your outlet connections? If so disconnect them.

Comment: no yellow warnings, restarted xcode over and over again, I've been trying everything before posting for the last 2 days

Comment: Is it definitely a problem with animation? If you comment that out in viewDidLoad the program runs?

Comment: Have you verified that the outlet is connected by putting a breakpoint in your animation method and checking the contents of blueView?

Comment: Oh, and you probably ought to be calling `[super viewDidLoad];` before you do your custom manipulations.

Comment: and as pointed out by @logan below, since the views aren't visible at viewDidLoad time, animations won't accomplish anything.  Move the animation set up to viewDidAppear.

Comment: just did that and still the image doesnt move

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add Method Like This:

```
- (void) animateToPoint:(CGPoint)point {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:3 animations:^{
        blueView.alpha = 1;
        blueView.center = point;
    }];
}
```

Call like this:

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    int distanceToSlide = 40; // will slide down 40px (use -40 to go up)
    CGPoint targetPoint = CGPointMake(blueView.center.x, blueView.center.y + distanceToSlide);
    [self animateToPoint:targetPoint];
}
```

#### NOTE

Notice that I put your animation call in `viewDidAppear` if you animate in `viewDidLoad` you won't see anything because your view isn't displayed yet.

If it's still not moving, make sure "useAutolayout" is not selected check this:

[image]

Just because I already built it, try this for tap to animate:

In your viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    UITapGestureRecognizer * tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]init];
    tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [tap addTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
}
```

Then, use these:

```
- (void) handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tap {
    int distanceToSlide = 40; // will slide down 40px (use -40 to go up)
    CGPoint targetPoint = CGPointMake(blueView.center.x, blueView.center.y + distanceToSlide);
    [self animateToPoint:targetPoint];
}

- (void) animateToPoint:(CGPoint)point {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:3 animations:^{
        blueView.alpha = 1;
        blueView.center = point;
    }];
}
```

Here's a way to loop it:

```
@implementation ImageBeaconViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    pointA = CGPointMake(40, 40);
    pointB = CGPointMake(250, 350);

    blueView.center = pointA;
}

- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self animate];
}

- (void) animate {
    if (CGPointEqualToPoint(_blueView.center, pointA)) {
        [self animateToPoint:pointB];
    }
    else {
        [self animateToPoint:pointA];
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void) animateToPoint:(CGPoint)point {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
        _blueView.alpha = 1;
        _blueView.center = point;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        if (finished) {
            [self animate];
        }
    }];
}

@end
```

Comment: this looks perfect to me! It's probably the best animation code to move an image i've seen so far! but stil.. bad news for me, when i get to the animation screen it crashes. I removed everything I did on the animation and added just this. If i remove this the app doesnt crash

Comment: That shouldn't be happening, I use this code all over my projects.  Something else is going on.  See my update regarding connection, is your view connected?  It sounds like there is a problem somewhere else in the project, is there any way for you to upload the project in its entirety to Github?

Comment: the bullet is filled in, now ive redone everything from the ground up, it doesnt crash anymore. I've then pasted your code but it the image doesnt move at all! It's driving me crazy

Comment: Make sure to deselect use autolayout.  See update.  Let me know if this works.

Comment: it was selected,IBD was hidden so i didnt notice, though.. i deselected it and it doesnt move.

Comment: And you're sending animation in viewDidLoad, it should be viewDidAppear?  Is the blueView appearing at all?

Comment: I'm sending the animation in viewDidAppear, just copied and pasted your code, blue view is appearing where i placed it in the storyboard but not moving, just as if there was no animation code

Comment: SOLVED! I used - (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated]; ...CODE...} Thanks a lot!

Comment: just one more thing, what do you suggest to make the animation loop?

Comment: Yay!!!! Just because I already built it for you, I added a tapGesture on my answer to show you how you could do it with a tap.

Comment: I'll save that because it's great! But now i'm looking for a way just to make this animation go on and repeat until i move to another screen. Thanks again!

Comment: Only because I'm feeling generous!! Here's an example of a way to animate it back and forth across the screen. Good luck with the rest of your project!

Comment: Wait, I changed it so it works right when it opens, check that one! We show thanks with upvotes on stack overflow!

Comment: No problem! Good luck with the rest of your project!

Answer (score 0):

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^{
        blueView.alpha = 1;
        blueView.center = CGPointMake(blueView.center.x , blueView.center.y + 100);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

       //if you need any thing after animation is done
    }];
```

this is them code for animation i have

Comment: I just copied and pasted it in -(void)animation{}.. it still crashes

Comment: just solved the crash problem, but.. now i copy and paste this and the image still doesnt move

Comment: - (void) viewDidAppear { [self animation]; }  call your function here not in viewdidload

Comment: i used that in viewDidAppear after Logan pointed that out but the image isnt moving